# Connect() every container view with Redux in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Must you connect each Tab and Screen to Redux (assuming you want state control over all of them) lower in your view tree?

index.ios.js

```
const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
)
```

appContainer.js

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Test: { screen: TestPage },
  Create: { screen: ButtonPage },
  Friends: { screen: FriendsPage }
})

render() {
    return(
        <Tabs />
    )
}
```

Do I need a

```
export default connect(state => ({

  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(/* insert actions here */, dispatch)
  })
)(/* insert view here */)
```

In each one, or is just having connect()(AppContainer) okay for global state management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you keeping them as seperate and have multiple connect() based on the functionalities of your views.

For example, your FriendsPage may have those functions related to friends actions (add, update, delete friends), and you can have

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FriendsPage);
```

Another tab container could be userView which manages common users:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserView);
```

So keep them as separated will make your code look neat and easy to maintain.